Confused about tire leakage, valve not attached
I’ve gotten a second hand mountain bicycle (felt brand), now the back tire is leaking air and is unusable.
First, I thought that the tube was burst and would need replacing. But now I am just confused about the way it looks at the moment. The valve can be completely detached from the tire. Would this mean it is tubeless?
(In that case I do not want to try dealing with it and would need to take it to repair shop :))

Can you post some photos?

Do you know how to replace a tube or tire? If not, try to learn it, saves a lot of money in the long run.
